# DIv top to bottom listing

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to list half portion of the for loop is to left side  and other is in the next is right side.how to solve it?

```
foreach ( $events as $post ) {        
            $start_date = tribe_get_start_date( $post, false, 'F d, Y'); 
            $end_date = tribe_get_end_date( $post, false, 'F d, Y');   
            if($i<=$number){
            ?>

            <div class="col-md-61 leftDiv">
            <div class="row1 outerDiv">
             <li class="ecs-event">
           <span class="duration time">
           <span class="tribe-event-date-start"><?php if(!empty($start_date)) { ?> <?php echo $start_date; ?> <?php } ?> <?php if(!empty($end_date) && $start_date != $end_date ) { ?> - <?php echo $end_date; ?> <?php } ?> </span>
           </span><span class="duration venue"><em>
            at </em><?php echo tribe_get_venue( $post ); ?></span>
            <h4 class="entry-title summary"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
            </h4>
            </li>
            </div> 
            </div>
            <?php } else {
            ?>
                  <div class="col-md-61 rightDiv">
              <div class="row1 outerDiv">
                 <li class="ecs-event">
               <span class="duration time">
               <span class="tribe-event-date-start"><?php if(!empty($start_date)) { ?> <?php echo $start_date; ?> <?php } ?> <?php if(!empty($end_date) && $start_date != $end_date ) { ?> - <?php echo $end_date; ?> <?php } ?> </span>
               </span><span class="duration venue"><em>
                at </em><?php echo tribe_get_venue( $post ); ?></span>
                <h4 class="entry-title summary"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
                </h4>
                </li>
                </div> 
                </div>
            <?php }?>
          <?php

          } ?>
```

please help to do that.I mean top to bottom listing as side by side

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

To point you to the idea you can check for even or odd item numbers to distribute your items.

Here is a generic code:

```php
$even = [];
$odd = [];

foreach(range(1,10) as $value) {
    if($value % 2 === 0) {
        // even divisable by 2 without rest
        $even[] = $value;
        continue;
    }
    $odd[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: but div position is changing.